# Tableview word wrap works in Simulator, but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-simulator, tableview

The following code wraps to multiple lines, as expected, on the 8.3 Simulator; but truncates the line when running on 8.3 iPhone 6. ????

Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Active Playlist";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

     cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
     cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    cell.textLabel.text = [playList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the two responsible lignes in the if-statement, so that they only get called when the cell is initiated?

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
}
```

Comment: At your suggestion; I tried it; makes no difference!

Comment: What does make it work,  is specifying a font size; e.g.:       [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0]];
(however, a font size of 23 fails), so, it must have something to do with height -BUT- that still begs the question of why it works fine in the simulator, but not the device, at font set in IB.

Comment: Would have been my next guess, setting the font. Sometimes the differences between the behaviour of the device and the one of the simulator are really weird, but usually it's the simulator where things stop working and not the device... 
Have you tried (dynamic and) different cell/textlabel heights?